# Cloudfront on rails not showing new images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using cloudfront as my CDN in my Rails app. I created my distribution and changed the enviroment file to enable the asset host.

Everything was working fine until I made a new deploy that included 3 new images. After restarting, everything looks fine but the 3 images. If I get the cloudfront URL and change the domain for my rails app domain the images load just fine, but if I use the CloudFront domain the images look like they weren't found.

Any ideas why this is happening? If I undestand correctly CloudFront doesn't have a delay, it loads the image as soon as the first request comes in.

Comment: Have you tried to open the broken link in another tab to examine it's URL? Perhaps the URL isn't set correctly?

Comment: Yeah, and it wasn't showing. I found the problem. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Sometime between the precompile and the restart of the server someone made a request and Cloudfront couldn't find the image so that's why it wasn't showing. I changed the image name, re-depoyed it and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

run **rake assets:precompile** then upload it.

or check the image path
it should begin with "/" like

```
<img src="/images/img.jpg"/> if you are images in public assets
```